# Move Subsites using Content and Structure gotchas?

Tags: content-and-structure, move

Can you share you're gotchas using Content and Structure? I've tried it and it seems to be ok (works with Pages / Versioning, etc), but would just like to be aware if there are any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not see any drawbacks as in this method all your versioning and metadata field preserve.
Only thing i found you cannot move the folder or list itself. You have to create blank list and then move the items.
http://blog.henryong.com/2008/01/21/how-to-movemigrate-sharepoint-list-itemsdocuments-and-preserve-metadata-properties-at-the-same-time/

Another thing, when you move the subsite then URL will be new and if you hardcoded it you need to update.

http://amatterofdegree.typepad.com/a_matter_of_degree/2009/02/issues-with-manage-content-and-structure-move-copy-functions-in-moss-2007.html